# Sort a mongo find() result by property child-count

Tags: mongodb-query

I need to fetch all documents that matches a list of 'propIds', and would like to sort the results by how many child-properties they have.

My documents are set up like the following, each document may contain zero or more fields properties.

I'd like to have the returned set sorted so the documents with the most fields is first.

```
{
  "propId" : 7,
  "fields" : {
    "fieldname1" : "fieldvalue1",
    ...
  }
}
```

I am able to create a find() query like this:

```
db.getCollection('col').find({"propId" : {"$in" : [7, 8, 9]}})
```

, but is at a loss of sorting the results.

I have been looking at the aggregate operator, but I'm not currently able to convert my find() logic (picking the documents that matches a list of ids) to an aggregate query that also uses the $sortByCount aggregation.

A pointer to how the aggregator works, and how I can convert the find-logic into an aggregate query, would be appreciated. Or a pointer to how I can sort the find-query by the count of "fields".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
let query = { propId: { $in : [7, 8, 9] } }; 

let result = await Collection.aggregate([
{$match: query},
{$project: { propId: 1, fields: 1, fieldArray: {$objectToArray: '$fields'} } },
{$project: { propId: 1, fields: 1, size: {$size: '$fieldArray'} } },
{$sort: size}
```

])